# ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead. python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-fold

I run the following code:

```
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

And got the following error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 6 lst_accu_stratified = []
> 7
> ----> 8 for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, Y):
> 9     x_train_fold, x_test_fold = X_scaled[train_index], X_scaled[test_index]
> 10     y_train_fold, y_test_fold = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
>
> 3 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py
> in _make_test_folds(self, X, y)
> 644             raise ValueError(
> 645                 'Supported target types are: {}. Got {!r} instead.'.format(
> --> 646                     allowed_target_types, type_of_target_y))
> 647
> 648         y = column_or_1d(y)
>
> ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got
> 'continuous' instead.

It doesn't make sense for this model not accepting continuous data. What's wrong?

Comment: Looking at the pasted code block you are trying to solve a reggression problem (mse as loss function and mae as metric) and asking about multilabel which qualifies for classification problems. You need to be descriptive and specific about the question

Comment: @think-maths Indeed it's about a regression problem and that's why I don't understand why I'm getting an error related to 'binary' or 'multiclass' data instead of 'continuous'.

Comment: The problem may be with `Y[train]`. The `y` parameter of the `fit()` cannot have the same columns as the `X` parameter.